# Помогите посчитать кол-во незаполненных полей на форме

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mvc

Имеется следующий код:

```
[HttpPost] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ФИО,Оценка1,Оценка2,Оценка3,Оценка4,Оценка5,Оценка6,Оценка7,Оценка8,Оценка9,Оценка10,Оценка11,Оценка12,Оценка13,Оценка14,Оценка15,Оценка16,Оценка17,Оценка18,Оценка19,Оценка20,Оценка21,Оценка22,Оценка23,Оценка24,Оценка25,Оценка26,Оценка27,Оценка28,Оценка29,Оценка30,Ср_балл,Итоговая_оценка")] Оценки оценки) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int koeff = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
        {
            if (оценки.Оценка[i].GetValueOrDefault() < 1) //<--ошибка тут
            {
                koeff++;
            }
        }
        db.Оценки.Add(оценки);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync(); 
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    } 

    return View(оценки); 
}
```

Модель:

```
public partial class I14 : DbContext 
{ 
   public I14() : base("name=I14") { } 
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
   { 
      throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException(); 
   } 
   public virtual DbSet<Оценки> Оценки { get; set; } 
   public virtual DbSet<Оценки_по_Компьютерным_сетям> Оценки_по_Компьютерным_сетям { get; set; } 
   public virtual DbSet<Оценки_по_Схемотехнике> Оценки_по_Схемотехнике { get; set; } 
}
```

Перебор не идет выдаёт ошибку Visual Studio, что элемент отсутствует, как можно попробовать реализовать еще? Может стоит в `Create.cshtml` реализовать подсчет через JavaScript?

Comment: Покажите свою модель

Comment: namespace AD.Models 
{ 
using System; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure; 

public partial class I14 : DbContext 
{ 
public I14() 
: base("name=I14") 
{ 
} 

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 

{ 
throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException(); 
} 

public virtual DbSet<Оценки> Оценки { get; set; } 
public virtual DbSet<Оценки_по_Компьютерным_сетям> Оценки_по_Компьютерным_сетям { get; set; } 
public virtual DbSet<Оценки_по_Схемотехнике> Оценки_по_Схемотехнике { get; set; } 
} 
}

Comment: А какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: "Оценки" не содержит определения для "Оценка" и не удалось найти метод расширения "Оценка", принимающий тип "Оценки" в качестве первого аргумента. При вызове быстрых действий рекомендует переименовать в оценки.Оценка1, но мне нужно чтобы он перебрал целиком форму которую он получил.